# Testing strategy for coupled systems

Tags: integration

We have 2 coupled applications: a ReadOnly view and an Admin management view.

The ReadOnly view is updated by changes from the Admin view.

Each application is owned by different teams. Each application should be deployed separately.

Basically, we're not clear on how to perform integration tests without needing to test both all the time.

Right now, we open the ReadOnly view, check some assumptions, open the Admin view and modify data, then reload the ReadOnly view to verify things have updated as expected.

Can anyone give some feedback on whether there's a better way?

In the current approach, we'll need to run 2 sets of integration tests for each change to the ReadOnly view or the Admin view. Indeed, we've got a few ReadOnly views (different products) that would be run in this matter.

Any feedback / thoughts is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, these two views both access some kind of state (presumably in a database), the AdminView is capable of modifying it as well as reading it, and the ReadOnly view can only read it. In which case...

Most of your tests (in particular, most of your automated tests) should only test one of these views.

- The ReadOnly view tests should take the form "here's some data, give it to the view, do the right widgets appear on the screen?"
- The AdminView tests should take the form "here's some data, perform an operation on it, does the modified data look right?" or perhaps "here's some data, do the right widgets appear, click this widget, does the modified data look right?".
- The "data" I'm nebulously referring to should have some kind of schema (be it a database schema, an XML schema, a JSON schema, whatever) that thoroughly, unambiguously and precisely defines the possible forms this data can take. As long as this schema never changes in a backwards-incompatible way, testing each view in isolation remains a valid strategy.

Of course you'll still want to test the two views together (including the glue code that talks to the real database), but those don't need to be super-thorough test suites. Indeed, trying to make a super-thorough integration test suite usually causes a hopeless combinatorial explosion in practice. It's the "unit tests" (or at least, the single-view tests) where it's worth spending time to get a tight feedback loop for red-green-refactor-style TDD and/or perfect code coverage to increase confidence in your tests' results.

Comment: The AdminView and ReadOnly view touch the same data. The AdminView has full access, while the ReadOnly view only shows the data in a meaningful way. Ideally, we'd need to test that a change on the AdminView doesn't break the ReadOnly view (a separately deployed application). I'm trying to get feedback as to whether or not both need to be tested.

Comment: Both of them definitely should be tested, my point is they should be tested *separately* from each other.

Comment: If the AdminView tests that it hasn't broken itself and the ReadOnly view tests that it hasn't broken itself, I fail to see how you imply that we arrive to AdminView hasn't broken ReadOnly without testing both together. Can you clarify that in your answer?

Comment: That's what my third bullet point about the "data" was for. The tests on each view will assume certain data as input and output. If the AdminView always outputs [1,2,3] after a Foobar operation, and the ReadOnly view always displays [1,2,3] correctly, then almost all of the ways a Foobar op might fail have been covered.

Comment: @dulac There's multiple levels of testing. Both the AdminView and ReadOnlyView teams should verify that their software works according to their requirements as they understand them. That is software acceptance testing. Afterwards, you would then test the 2 software systems together. That's system testing. 2 separate activities. If more than 2 software systems exist then sometimes there's a 3rd level of testing called integration testing where parts of the system are tested with each other to make sure they work together. There are shortcuts but conceptually all of these are separate activities